# programming in JavaScript for leap-year by user input

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and I am trying to create a function which tells whether a given year is a leap year or not. I want to take value from the `form>input`
please correct where did I mistake.

[my code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1753LRD3L97uWWqF4grBZyQo7JXU0I2OX):

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3 style="text-transform: capitalize;">please enter the current year to check the leap year</h3>
    <form>
        Current Year:<br>
        <input type="text" name="years" value="2018"><br>
    </form>
    <button style="padding: 5px 10px; background-color:aqua; font-weight: bold;
    margin: 20px;" onclick="hello()">Let's go!</button>
    <p id="leap"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**javascript.js**

```
function hello(){
    var leapYear = document.forms.years.value;
    var numb = parseInt(leapYear, 10);
    var result = numb % 4;
    if (result === 0){
        document.getElementById("leap").innerHTML= "Yes, This Is A Leap Year"
    }
    else(
        document.getElementById("leap").innerHTML= "No, This Is Not A Leap Year"
    );
}
```

Comment: If you would, please post all the code relevant to the question *in the question itself* - don't hide it behind a link. You shouldn't tell potential helpers who would otherwise love to help that they have to navigate offsite just to have an idea of what you're working with. If the link breaks, the question could be rendered useless to future readers. Please edit your code into the question in a [MCVE], or the question might get closed, thanks.

Comment: i have told u, i am facing problem in pasting the link in question box

Comment: you need something like a queryselector, give the input an id and you can do document.querySelector("#id").value to get value in input

Comment: Chris Li thanx man you made my day. It solved my problem in one go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go: read the comments to see what changes I've done.

```js
function hello(){
    var leapYear = document.getElementById("leapInput").value;
    //changed value of leapYear from "document.forms.years.value" to   document.getElementById("leapInput").value
    var numb = parseInt(leapYear, 10);
    var result = numb % 4;
    if (result === 0){
        document.getElementById("leap").innerHTML= "Yes, This Is A Leap Year"
    }
    else(
        document.getElementById("leap").innerHTML= "No, This Is Not A Leap Year"
    );
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3 style="text-transform: capitalize;">please enter the current year to check the leap year</h3>
    <form>
        Current Year:<br>
        <input id="leapInput" type="text" name="years" value="2018"><br> 
        <!--Added id of "leapInput" to the <input> above-->
    </form>
    <button style="padding: 5px 10px; background-color:aqua; font-weight: bold;
    margin: 20px;" onclick="hello()">Let's go!</button>
    <p id="leap"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

And, when you ask questions on this site, post your code in the question itself. If you can't, for some reason, use the website [CodePen](https://codepen.io). Create a pen with your code, and then link it to the question.

Comment: hey, thank you so much!!!   i can't believe i made a silly mistake...   thanks again

Comment: No problemo, bro ;)